# Multivariable Calculus: Line Integrals (Directed Curve)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I have this math problem, that I got a bit confused on. I just need to know whether or not I did it correctly. Thanks!

Question:

> Calculate $\oint_c xe^{z}dx+yzdy+xe^{y}dz$ over the directed curve $C$
>   that is parameterized by $r(t) = t^2i+t^3j+t^4k$, $0\leq t \leq1$.

---

Work:

$r(t)=<t^2, t^3, t^4>$

$r'(t)=<2t, 3t^2, 4t^3>$

$x=t^2, y=t^3, z=t^4$

$dx=2t, dy=3t^2, dz=4t^3$

I plug into the equation: $\oint_c xe^{z}dx+yzdy+xe^{y}dz$

$\int_0^1 (t^2)e^{(t^4)}(2t)+(t^3)(t^4)(3t^2)+(t^2)e^{t^3}(4t^3) dt$

= $\int_0^1 2t^3e^{t^4} + 3t^9 + 4t^5e^{t^3} dt$

= $\frac{49+15(e-1)}{30}$

Comment: This is perfect my dear!! ;)

Comment: I did an effort, could you vote for my comment

Comment: Yup, no problem

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect my dear!! ;)

Now, you could vote again ;)